# What's the name of these two surfaces?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, algebraic-geometry, surfaces, visualization

[image]
I've plot two implicit surfaces which are shown in the above, I only know their expression, but I don't know how to call them.

Comment: Topologically, the first is a 3-fold torus, and the second is a 5-fold torus. Geometrically, one cannot be more specific without knowing where you got these.

Comment: You said these two are implicit surfaces, is it defined by a level set of a function?

Comment: What does 3-fold and 5-fold torus mean?

Comment: *I only know their expression* - Well, we don't. $(-1)$

Answer (score 2):

The second one appears to belong to a family of surfaces defined by Banchoff based on the [Chmutov surfaces](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChmutovSurface.html) of order $n$.  Explicitly, the implicit equation is given by $$3+8(x^4+y^4+z^4) = 8(x^2+y^2+z^2).$$  The first one is not known to me.  It appears to have a tetrahedral symmetry.

Comment: Yes，they are defined by a level set of a function